# Nohup seems to be stuck

Tags: aix

I have ran a command here at work that my coworkers told me to run:

[image]

They told me that this command was supposed to run in background, once it takes hours and hours to run ... but after running the command, the prompt stucked in this "Sending output to nohup.out" and it's like this for more than 1 hour.

**Question:** can I shutdown my computer? Sorry about my ignorance, I do not understand anything about it. By the way, this is a windows command prompt, connected to an AIX server using Telnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are at a command prompt, the output of the previous command wrote on top of it. Yes, you can disconnect from the remote system and the command will continue (it will ignore the HUP signal sent on disconnect). Yes, you can shut down your Windows client.